# Pulling content from one node only

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to pull a specific node from my xml document, but continue to get content from all nodes. I am testing for a specific jNumber by passing the number to the xslt in a variable set with the fragment call ($jNumber).

```
<xsl:if test="products/product/jNumber[. = $jNumber]">
    <div class="floatLeft padTop10 margLeft10" style="width:185px;">
        <xsl:for-each select="products/product/topicFocus">
            <div id="tab{./@tab}focus" class="linksUnit padBtm3" style="display:block;"><xsl:text>» </xsl:text><a href="#" class="bold" target="_blank"><em><xsl:value-of select="./@name" /></em></a></div>
            <div id="tab{./@tab}ready" class="linksUnit padBtm3" style="display:none;"><xsl:text>» </xsl:text><a href="#" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="./@name" /></a></div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="products/product/topicLeft">
            <div id="tab{./@tab}focus" class="linksUnit padBtm3" style="display:none;"><xsl:text>» </xsl:text> <a href="#" class="bold" target="_blank"><em><xsl:value-of select="./@name" /></em></a></div>
            <div id="tab{./@tab}ready" class="linksUnit padBtm3" style="display:block;"><xsl:text>» </xsl:text><a href="#" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="./@name" /></a></div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:if>
```

It was my understanding that the if statement would cause only nodes that tested true to be displayed. Is that true?

```
<products>
    <product>
        <jNumber>1234</jNumber>
        <name>Product #1</name>
        <numberoftabs>12</numberoftabs>
        <!-- Links at top of the page -->
        <topicFocus tab="1" name="Accessories"></topicFocus>
        <!--topicLeft tab="2" name="Configuration examples"></topicLeft-->
        <topicLeft tab="2" name="Resources (white papers, datasheets, etc.)"></topicLeft>
        <topicLeft tab="3" name="Download software"></topicLeft>
        <topicLeft tab="4" name="FAQs"></topicLeft>
        <topicLeft tab="5" name="Interoperability"></topicLeft>
        <!--topicLeft tab="6" name="MIBs"></topicLeft-->
        <topicRight tab="6" name="Technical documentation">
            <subCategory tab="7">Management and Configuration</subCategory>
            <subCategory tab="8">Archived</subCategory>
        </topicRight>
        <topicRight tab="9" name="Related links"></topicRight>
        <topicRight tab="10" name="Support form"></topicRight>
    </product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 2):

The xsl:for-each is nested in the xsl:if, but the for-each isn't limited by the if.

I don't see where jNumber is in the XML you provided, but you can make the for-each respect the same limit as your enclosing if which would choose to display the region or not.

```
<xsl:for-each select="products/product[jNumber = $jNumber]/topicFocus">
```

The line above says:
starting with the current scope look for products - which have product - which has a jNumber equal to $jNumber - and then look at the topicFocus nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Jason Aller's answer is certainly correct, but I think you have a lot more opportunities to improve that XSLT.  Wherever you have XPath like:

```
select="products/product/topicFocus"
```

you are looking at all `products` elements that are children of the context node (i.e. the element that your template is transforming, or that your `for-each` loop is currently positioned at), and then their `product` children, and then any `topicFocus` children beneath that.  That's either going to find a lot of nodes (if the context node is the parent of your `products` element) or none at all (if the context node is a `product` element, unless your `product` element have `products` children).

It's a lot easier to work with XSLT if you use templates as your primary tool.  A template transforms a node into a result.  In your case, you want to transform `product` nodes into `div`s.  You also want to transform `topicFocus` and `topicLeft` elements into pairs of `div`s.

If your templates' design reflects that, it looks like this:

```
<!-- 
   this, somewhere in the main template, finds the specific product
   element you're looking for and transforms it.
 -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="products/product[jNumber = $jNumber]/>

<xsl:template match="product">
  <div class="floatLeft padTop10 margLeft10" style="width:185px;">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="topicFocus"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="topicLeft"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topicFocus | topicLeft">
  <xsl:variable name="display1">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name() = 'topicFocus'>none</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>block</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="display2">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name() = 'topicFocus'>block</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>none</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <div id="tab{@tab}focus" class="linksUnit padBtm3" style="display:{$display1};">
    <xsl:text>» </xsl:text>
    <a href="#" class="bold" target="_blank">
       <em>
         <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
       </em>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab{@tab}ready" class="linksUnit padBtm3" style="display:{$display2};">
    <xsl:text>» </xsl:text>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </a>
  </div>                                          
</xsl:template>
```

I've simplified a couple of other things here, too:

- Since it looks to me as though the HTML your transform is emitting for `topicFocus` and `topicLeft` elements is identical except for how the `display` style is set, I've created a single template for them.
- I've used whitespace and indenting in the template so that the structure of the HTML is apparent; this will make maintaining it a zillion times easier, and will have no effect on how the transform produces its output.
- I've removed the redundant `./` that you had in front of all of your attributes.